# Unable to connect to remote SQL database using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyodbc

our organization has a remote SQL database which I am trying to connect to using pyodbc.

Below is the test code:-

```
import pyodbc
                      
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<name>.org;DATABASE=<dbname>;UID=<username>;PWD=<pwd>;PORT=<port>;')
```

However, I am unable to connect and get the below error when I try to connect using pyodbc.

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access
> denied.(17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53); [08001]
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
> (0)')

I also tried using another tool to connect to remote database (HeidiSQL) and this work correctly. I am able to connect to the database.

[image: Connecting using HeidiSQL]

But I do not understand why I am unable to connect using pyodbc.
I also tried using the IP address instead of the server name.

so I also tried the below in pyodbc connect:-

```
SERVER=<name>.org,<port>

SERVER=<IP address>,<port>

SERVER=<IP address>
```

I also updated the ODBC SQL Server Driver.

I also tried with MySQL ODBC 3.51 driver :-

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=<name>.org;DATABASE=<dbname>;UID=<username>;PWD=<pwd>;PORT=<port>;')
```

but then I get error :

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
> (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

When I try with SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Driver I get error :

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=<name>.o`rg;DATABASE=<dbname>;UID=<username>;PWD=<pwd>;PORT=<port>;')
```

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server
> Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection
> to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL
> Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0); [08001]
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string
> attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A
> network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online. (53)')

I also used this guide [Microsoft guide connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)

Since I am using docker container for the python application, I hope that this would work to connect with the database.

Could someone please suggest what could be the issue OR how could I solve this?
Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: I don't understand German, so can't be sure, but that image suggests you are (successfully) connecting to a MySQL instance, yet your code is attempting to connect to a SQL Server instance; the technologies are completely different.

Comment: _"Since we are using docker container, I hope that this would work."_ SQL Server in Docker, or the Python app in Docker?

Also; what happens if you `ping` the SQL Server address?

Comment: @Larnu oh okay. thanks. I try with MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver.

Comment: @gvee It works fine when I try to ping with:   ping <name>.org  . I get reply like reply from IP address. and the python app in Docker, I want to connect this to the MySQL database.

Comment: @Larnu I tried with driver DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}  but now I get error "pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: @GordThompson  oh thanks so much ! yes, i tried it and I found that I have MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver. and It connects with this driver :) thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

As commented/answered by @Gord Thompson and @larnu, @gvee

I checked list returned by pyodbc.drivers()

```
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers() )
```

Where it returned

> ['SQL Server', 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0', 'SQL Server Native
> Client RDA 11.0', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 'PostgreSQL
> ANSI(x64)', 'PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)', 'Amazon Redshift (x64)',
> 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)', 'Microsoft Excel Driver
> (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)', 'Microsoft Access Text Driver
> (*.txt, *.csv)', 'MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver', 'MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode
> Driver']

I could connect with "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver"

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=<name>.org;DATABASE=<dbname>;UID=<username>;PWD=<pwd>;PORT=<port>;')
```